# Percona Toolkit Installation Error

Tags: installation, percona

> [root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh percona-toolkit-2.2.7-1.noarch.rpm
>   error: Failed dependencies:   perl(DBD::mysql) >= 1.0 is needed by
>   percona-toolkit-2.2.7-1.noarch    perl(Time::HiRes) is needed by
>   percona-toolkit-2.2.7-1.noarch    perl(IO::Socket::SSL) is needed by
>   percona-toolkit-2.2.7-1.noarch

How to solve above dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error on an Amazon Linux box (AWS EC2). Here's what I did to get Percona toolkit installed.

```
# Installs Percona's Perl deps...
yum install perl-Time-HiRes
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
yum install perl-IO-Socket-SSL     # I actually didn't need this one,
                                   # but based on your error you probably will.

# Install Percona toolkit
rpm -Uhv http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-toolkit/LATEST/RPM/percona-toolkit-2.2.7-1.noarch.rpm
```

I'd suggest getting the URL for the Percona toolkit RPM from their website under the "Download Latest" link. (Latest for me at the time of this post was 2.2.7.) The website offers RPM and deb formats; just choose RPM, and then use the link it shows.

I know this doesn't address the OP's problem as described, but it does address his root problem (can't get Percona toolkit installed). I agree with Peter's answer in that a package manager like yum or apt should be used... if for no other reason than handling nasty dependency hell, but I don't know Percona's yum or apt repo... or if they even still have one.

Edit: Also, those are just the Percona toolkit dependencies that *I* had missing on *my* box. You may have more or less. Another EC2 instance of mine already had all of the Perl dependencies installed, so all I needed to do was run the `rpm` command. A Percona repo sure would be great to have!

Comment: This helped me! The only difference was that I had to install `yum install perl-TermReadKey` instead of `Time-HiRes`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install this with its dependencies.

```
yum install percona-toolkit
```

Tracking back the dependencies, checking the conflicts/replacements, and downloading the needed packages from the net isn't a trivial or low-level task. Thus not the rpm does this, but yum.

Comment: in operating, yum is not working. could you provide some other ways to install.

Comment: @Peter The original poster is asking you for more information to clarify your answer

Comment: On an Amazon Linux AMI, I get this:

> yum install percona-toolkit
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/2014.03 | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/2014.03 | 2.3 kB     00:00
No package percona-toolkit available.
Error: Nothing to do

A blog suggested installing the Percona repo via RPM, but that ended up breaking yum. I think it was an old repo URL. Anyone know Percona's latest repo?

Comment: I get `No package percona-toolkit available.` when I try that.